# The NUNIT automation scripts are NOT running from Task Scheduler

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to execute the NUNIT scripts using batch file. I am trying to run this batch file from Task scheduler to make it unattended and run regularly.

But bat file runs and provide output that window which is trying to perform automation is not opened.

Those are the parameters I'm using to launch the NUnit console:

```
cd C:\Program Files\NUnit.org\nunit-console 
NUNIT3-CONSOLE D:\nunit\UnitTestProject1.dll --result="D:\nunit\TestResult.XML"
```

My code looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod1()
 { 
   IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.oford.com"); 
 }
```

Is there any way to run the batch files in unattended mode ?

Answer (score 0):

I've started my first setup with the same approach, but some user privileges and Windows settings may interrupt at any time.

> Is there any way to run the batch files in unattended mode ?

Yes, you can use a [CI server](https://xebialabs.com/the-ultimate-devops-tool-chest/continuous-integration/). It is really to setup, free and powerful once you get the hang out of it. I would recommend [Jenkins](https://xebialabs.com/technology/jenkins/), because of its great community and vast resources (tutorials,plugins etc.). Configuring a [basic job](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm) takes no more than five minutes. The reporting is also great.

Comment: HI I just added the nunit command line to Jenkins , still it did not open the browser on clicking build now option.

Comment: can u provide log? what params are you passing to the nunit console?

Comment: cd C:\Program Files\NUnit.org\nunit-console
NUNIT3-CONSOLE D:\nunit\UnitTestProject1.dll --result="D:\nunit\TestResult.XML"

This was the command i gave at build as a executable command prompt.

When i gave build now option, I was expecting the browser to be launched , but it didn happen. Do i need to di something else to run the program??

The NUNIT test had a simple test  with the below code 
[Test]public void TestMethod1()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.onecognizant.com");
        }
    }

Comment: I've moved your code to the question body. The NUnit params look OK to me. The ChromeDriver worries me - try with the Firefox build-in one. I see that you are not passing the ````path\to\the\chronedriver.exe" as param when creating the driver! Sometimes Chrome also messes with open connections and all. Try basic setup.

Comment: When i run the commond from Cmd prompt it launches the chromedriver & it works...

Only thing i want to know is that if i configure the same command in JENKINS , and when I use BUILD now option....THe same browser wont be launched ??

Comment: Is your Jenkins on remote server? If yes, check its [user's privileges](http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.bg/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html)

Comment: Jenkins is installed on the same PC. Admin rights only.

Comment: Looking at the log, I see your test running for 3sec and passing. Could be something small, but I am out of ideas atm why you don't see the browser. My only guess is that the browser may run in virtual desktop. I've seen such while using TeamCity as a service.